# How to run sub commands from inside the Cobra root command

Tags: go, command-line, command-line-interface, go-cobra

I have a Go Cobra CLI app, and I would like to run subcommands based on user input in an infinite loop when the root command is run without any subcommands.

`myapp` has 3 subcommands; `list`, `delete` and `create`. Typically, Cobra apps work by running `myapp list [args]` etc. but I want to be able to run `myapp` and be presented with an interface that accepts list, delete and create without the prefix of `myapp`.

So instead of:

```sh
$ myapp list /files
f1 f2 f3
$ myapp create /newfile
$ myapp delete /newfile
```

It would be:

```sh
$ myapp
> list /files
f1 f2 f3
> create /newfile
> delete /newfile
```

I could just run a loop when the root command is executed and accept string inputs and run the corresponding commands, but there are a lot more commands and this is a lot of additional work that is duplicating functionality that already exists in cobra.

Here is the cobra `rootCmd`:

```golang
// rootCmd represents the base command when called without any subcommands
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "server",
    Short: "A brief description of your application",
    Long:  ``,
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        // loop here and run commands based on user input
    },
}

func Execute() {
    cobra.CheckErr(rootCmd.Execute())
}
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: By "running a loop and accepting string inputs" did you mean to have a giant `switch` with all possible commands? Because you could also just run a loop to accept string inputs and then loop over all subcommands of `rootCmd` from `rootCmd.Commands()` until you find a match to the input and execute that

Comment: @kolaente yes that's what I meant, but I'm trying to avoid the giant switch - since there will be a lot of commands, each having their own varying parameters.

Comment: Then what about looping over all commands from `rootCmd.Commands()`?